# Condition to display image in Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css, image, visibility

I'm looking for create a small javascript code to display images if their src is valid.

I have to separate the script to the html page for better organisation.

Here is what I did :
HTML

```
<img id="thmb" src= "http://blog.lefigaro.fr/bd/img-sanctuaire.png" width="50px" height="50px" alt="" ;>
```

JavaScript

```
var thumbnail = document.images.thmb;

    if(thumbnail.src)
    {
        if(thumbnail.onerror)
        {
            thumbnail.src = "http://blog.lefigaro.fr/bd/img-sanctuaire.png";
        }
    }
    else
    {
        thumbnail.style.display = "none";
    }
```

Bu it doesn't work, when I empty the src code in HTML, the border of the image still in the page. And if I write a wrong URL, we can't see the image set in the JavaScript.
Here is the JSFiddle to experiment it.
http://jsfiddle.net/gUb8X/

I'm a beginner in JavaScript.
Thank you !

Comment: Well do you have any event-listeners attached to the document?

Comment: If your image src looks like this `img src=""`, browsers may still make a request to the page itself (actual behavior varies by browser). You should avoid it if at all possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are too late with the test.

Try this

[**Live Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/mplungjan/77hup/)

```
window.onload=function() {
  var thumbContainer = document.getElementById("thmbDiv");
  var thumbnail = document.createElement("img");
  thumbnail.onload=function() {
    thumbContainer.appendChild(thumbnail);
  }
  thumbnail.src = "http://blog.lefigaro.fr/bd/img-sanctuaire.png";
}
```

Now replace your image with a div with id thmbDiv

if you put placeholders or hide all images you want to test, you can get the src from a data attribute.

[**Live Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/mplungjan/4x58g/)

```
window.onload=function() {
  var imgs = document.images; // or document.getElementsByClassName("testImage");
  for (var i=0, n=imgs.length;i<n;i++) { 
    var theImage = imgs[i];   
    var src = theImage.getAttribute("data-src");
    if (src) {
      theImage.onerror=function() {
        this.style.display="none"; // or this.parentNode.removeChild(this);
      }
    }
    theImage.src=src;  
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

A neat inline solution would be this

DEMO http://jsfiddle.net/LstNS/25/

```
<img src="rando/path" id="image" onerror="this.style.display='none';"/>
```

jQuery:
You can use an ajax call to check if the image file exists

```
$.ajax({
    url:'http://yourhost/someimage.ext',
    type:'HEAD',
    error: function()
    {
        //file does not exist
    },
    success: function()
    {
        //file exists do something here
    }
});
```

DEMO http://jsfiddle.net/LstNS/24/

As you can see in the demo, the second image is not loaded and presented as a broken image as it does not exist.

A non jQuery version would be

```
var img = document.getElementById("myImg");
img.onerror = function () { 
    this.style.display = "none";
}
```

Comment: There is no jquery tag on the question

Answer (score 0):

Your code now tests for `thumbnail.src`, which means that you are testing for the existence of an `src` propery, which always exists for a syntactically valid `img` element. Then you test for the existence of an `onerror` event handler, and since there is none, you take a branch that does nothing.

A way that works is to use an `onerror` attribute in the `img` element and make it remove the element (or remove it from rendering, but actually removing the element is more logical, and safer):

```
<img id="thmb" src= "http://blog.lefigaro.fr/bd/img-sanctuaire.png"
  width="50" height="50" alt="" onerror="rm(this)">
<script>
function rm(elem) {
  elem.parentNode.removeChild(elem); }
</script>
```

Unfortunately, you can’t do this so with a loop that traverses through all `img` elements. If you try that, your code will run only after the image loading has been performed, so it would be too late to try to set `onerror` handlers on them.

Answer (score 0):

I just found a little trick to make it possible. That doesn't follow the convention but it works. I just use the "alt" image keyword as the "src" keyword, and the JavaScript gives the src equals to alt attribute found in the html.

```
<img id="thmb" width="50px" height="50px" alt="http://blog.lefigaro.fr/bd/img-sanctuaire.png" ;>
```

Javascript :

```
var img = document.getElementById("thmb");
img.src= img.alt;

img.onerror = function () {
    img.style.display = "none";
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/LstNS/28/

To more, because I have to use a function to return all the final html code, I did this :

```
display: function (data) {
                            var pid = data.record.project_id;
                            var thb = data.record.Thumbnail;
                            var base_url = "<?php echo base_url('project');?>/";
                            function checkImg(){
                                try
                                {
                                    var thumbnail = document.createElement("img");
                                    thumbnail.src = thb;
                                } catch(err) {
                                    //
                                }
                                if(thumbnail.height > 0){
                                    var result = 'src="' + thb + '"';
                                }
                                else
                                {
                                    var result = 'style="display:none;"';
                                }
                                return result;
                            }
                            return '<a href="' + base_url + pid + '"><img id="thumbnail" ' + checkImg() + '" width="50px" height="50px" ></a>';
                        }
```

I have to thank you for all your answers which permit me to find a good way to do it !
If you have comments to do, don't hesitate ! ;)